# serverless deploy lambda@edge with specific dependency

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-edge

I want to deploy function for Converting images to WebP from CloudFront as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/nona-web/converting-images-to-webp-from-cdn-9433b56a3d52)

But I want to use `serverless` framework and I have created following `serverless.yml` & my [handler.js](https://pastebin.com/raw/71Bn0hW0)

```
service: viewer-image-request

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1

resources:
  Resources:
    LambdaAtEdgeRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: lambda-at-edge
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
                  - edgelambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

functions:
  viewer-request:
    handler: handler.handler
    role: LambdaAtEdgeRole

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
  include:
    - node_modules/path
    - node_modules/useragent
```

When I deploy this it uploads `lru-cache`, `os-tempdir`, `pseudomap`, `tmp`, `useragent`, `yallist` to node_modules. Code only required `useragent` & `path`, but `path` doesn't get uploaded.

After deploy size of the function is `91kB`

[image]

When I try to deploy it Lambda@Edge I gate this message

[image]

What I am missing here ?

Comment: Your 'LambdaAtEdgeRole' resource line assisted me in figuring out why my execution role was misconfigured, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that [the default values for serverless.yml](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) are:

```yaml
provider:
  memorySize: 1024
  timeout: 6
```

According to the error message, these are the values that you need to use:

```yaml
provider:
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 5
```